# Is it possible to add an interface to an existing type?

Tags: vb.net

I've developed some serialization code for my types.  They all share a common interface to facilitate the serialization logic.  Would it be possible to also add that interface to some basic types like `Integer` or `String` so I could pass one of those basic type values into my serialization logic and have it work?  I'm imagining something along the lines of extension methods, but adding an interface rather than a method?  I'm sure I could come up with some way to do it using late-binding, but I'd like to avoid that, if possible.

Comment: Vague question , you may want to explain more and show your code

Comment: Why not use extension methods, as  you suggest?

Comment: I want to be able to pass the objects to a method or collection as instance of an interface. If i passed them as object with an extension method, the late binding would have a pretty narly effect on the performance. Also I generally dislike using object as type since I'm pedantic like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  It is not possible to extend an existing type to make it implement an interface (short of adding `Implements IMyInterface` to the top of the code for that type, that is).  The closest thing to that would be to create a derived class which adds the interface to the base class.  If you override the `CType` operator you could even make it so values could be seamlessly converted from one type to the other without explicitly casting them.  However, since you mentioned `String` and `Integer` as the types that you want to extend, that is not even possible.  You can't create a new type that inherits from `String` because `String` is defined as `NotInheritable`.  Similarly, you can't create a new type that inherits from `Integer` because `Integer` is a `Structure`, not a `Class`.  Structures do not support inheritance.

Therefore, the best option that you have would be to create a new class which wraps the core value, extends it by implementing the interface, and then overrides the `CType` operator to make it simple to convert between the core type and the wrapper type.  For instance, let's say you had an interface like this:

```
Public Interface IWritable
    Sub Write()
End Interface
```

And you had a method that took an argument of that type, like this:

```
Private Sub TestWrite(writableObject As IWritable)
    writableObject.Write()
End Sub
```

If you needed to pass an `Integer` into that method, you could make a wrapper class like this:

```
Public Class WritableInteger
    Implements IWritable

    Public Sub New(value As Integer)
        Me.Value = value
    End Sub

    Public Property Value As Integer

    Public Sub Write() Implements IWritable.Write
        Console.Write(Value)
    End Sub

    Overloads Shared Widening Operator CType(value As Integer) As WritableInteger
        Return New WritableInteger(value)
    End Operator

    Overloads Shared Widening Operator CType(value As WritableInteger) As Integer
        Return value.Value
    End Operator
End Class
```

Since the `CType` operator is overloaded as `Widening`, that means that you can convert the value between the two types without casting (even with `Option Strict On`).  For instance, this works:

```
Dim w As WritableInteger = New WritableInteger(5)
Dim i As Integer = w
w = i
```

Unfortunately, since `TestWrite` is asking for an `IWritable` rather than a `WritableInteger`, you can't just call `TestWrite` with an `Integer`, like this:

```
Dim i As Integer = 5
TestWrite(5)  'This won't work!
```

The compiler knows that it needs to convert the `Integer` to an `IWritable` object, but since any number of types may implement that interface, it doesn't automatically try to figure out if any of them provide a `CType` operator for that.  Since there may be multiple types that allow widening conversions from `Integer` to `IWritable`, it just throws up its hands and cries fowl.  Therefore, even though the widening conversion is declared, you still have to explicitly cast the type in a case like that.  For instance:

```
Dim i As Integer = 5
TestWrite(CType(i, WritableInteger))
```

Or, perhaps more simply:

```
Dim i As Integer = 5
TestWrite(New WritableInteger(5))
```

You could make it more convenient by creating overloads for all the common types that will need to be wrapped.  For instance, if you created an overload to the `TestWrite` method, like this:

```
Public Sub TestWrite(value As Integer)
    TestWrite(New WritableInteger(value))
End Sub
```

Then you could easily call it like this:

```
TestWrite(5)
```

Converting back from an `IWritable` variable to an `Integer`, though, is even more difficult.  For instance:

```
Dim w As IWritable = New WritableInteger(5)
Dim i As Integer = w  ' This won't work!
Dim i2 As Integer = CType(w, Integer)  ' Whis won't work either!
```

If you need to do that, you'd actually have to first cast it to a `WritableInteger` (and know that it is that type of object in the first place), for instance:

```
Dim w As IWritable = New WritableInteger(5)
If TypeOf w Is WritableInteger Then
    Dim i As Integer = CType(w, WritableInteger)
End If
```

Unfortunately, there's really no way to make that any easier while still maintaining the safety of the compile-time type checking.

Finally it's also worth mentioning that, if you decide to make a wrapper like that, and the implementation of the interface is the same regardless of the wrapped type, then you could implement it as a generic type, like this:

```
Public Class Writable(Of T)
    Implements IWritable

    Public Sub New(value As T)
        Me.Value = value
    End Sub

    Public Property Value As T

    Public Sub Write() Implements IWritable.Write
        Console.Write(Value)
    End Sub

    Overloads Shared Widening Operator CType(value As T) As Writable(Of T)
        Return New Writable(Of T)(value)
    End Operator

    Overloads Shared Widening Operator CType(value As Writable(Of T)) As T
        Return value.Value
    End Operator
End Class
```

Then you could call the `TestWrite` method like this:

```
TestWrite(New Writable(Of Integer)(5))
TestWrite(New Writable(Of String)("Hello World"))
```